# Combining duplicates from one column and showing values from second column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set with several columns but, for this purpose I am only interested in two and have moved them to a separate sheet. I know Column A has several duplicates and I would like to combine them but, I do not want to loose the individual data from Column B. Is it possible to combine the duplicates in column A and in columns B,C,D,... show the information that was associated with the row?
Please Reference the image below I couldn't figure out how to format like I have seen on here.

[image: Current and Desired Formats]

I am open to any other solutions that are similar so long as I can see the distribution of column B. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add a column with a counter:

```
=COUNTIF(B$1:B2,B2)
```

and then pivot:

[image: SO48268652 example]

Adjust labels to suit.

Comment: Thank you, this accomplishes what I was looking for.